# Is it good or bad to delegate to another constructor (using this()) within a constructor

Tags: java, constructor, this

Oracle reference doesn't tell about best practice of *this* keyword while we overload constructors. Can anyone suggest the best practice for it?

## Option 1: delegate to another constructor

```
public class A {
    private int x, y, z, p;  

    public A() {
        this(1,1,1,1);
    }

    public A(int x, int y, int z, int p) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        this.p = p;
    }
}
```

and

## Option 2: set each field rather than delegating

```
public class A {
    private int x, y, z, p;  

    public A() {
        this.x = 1;
        this.y = 1;
        this.z = 1;
        this.p = 1;
    }

    public A(int x, int y, int z, int p) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        this.p = p;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's an excellent explanation of the this keyword in the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html), in which it uses your first example.

Comment: By the way, you are not overriding constructors, but overloading them.

Comment: Option 1 all the way. Constructors like that in Option 2 have caused me no end of grief previously. Imagine you need to extend the constructors to initialise an extra field. Now imagine, you thought the constructors were chained, but they weren't, so some objects get the new field initialised and others don't.

Comment: @sbat I was referring the same before posting the question.

Comment: @meskobalazs My typo mistake. thanks for correction. crux remains same.

Comment: Thanks :) It clears my doubt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first one is the best.

It is referenced multiple times in the offical docs and in many books. It is a specific case of *method-chaining* or, as others noted in the comments, *telescoping constructors*. They allows you to write less code and to not repeat yourself (DRY).

You can find that approach everywhere in solid libraries like [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org) and also in the best practices of other platforms. Finally, the famous book Thinking in Java, use this form in the [Initialization & Cleanup chapter](http://www.cs.hut.fi/Docs/Eckel/TIJ3ed/TIJ306.htm) (*Calling constructors from constructors* section).

Comment: Use DRY concept, whenever applicable. (i.e. Do not repeat yourself)

Comment: It's called "telescoping constructors" btw. I use this very often, DRY ftw.

Comment: I cannot agree more (+1). I'd just add that this is special case of code reuse and encapsulation. Although code written in second constructor of first case is simple but this is a code and it should be never duplicated.

Comment: _telescopic Constructor_ and _DRY_ helped in me in my cause. Many beginner programmers dont know about this etiquette. thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

The first sample is preferable, this is called constructor-telescoping or constructor-chaining. Following this pattern the primary constructor (which takes a parameter for each field that can be set) can be called by secondary constructors that set defaults.

In the first example there is only one place where the instance variable is assigned, while in the second example both constructors have to know which instance variable to use, so the first one has less cut-n-paste duplication.

In addition, this way initialization proceeds in a single consistent path rather than allowing totally different ways to initialize the object, where initialization results could differ depending on which constructor was called. This way any code added to the primary constructor will always be called.

I borrowed the terms "primary constructor" and "secondary constructor" from Scala. In Scala this style is enforced by the language, option 2 is not allowed.