# Why Would a Default Constructor and a Parameterized Constructor Both Be In a Class?

Tags: java, constructor

I have a segment of Java code here where an abstract class has been created. Something I'm confused on with this segment, though, is why the writer decided to use both a default constructor and a parameterized constructor.

```
abstract class Person {
    String personName;
    String personID;

    //default consructor
    Person() {
    
    }

    //parameterized constructor
    //assigns personName and personID to object at time of creation
    Person(String personName, String personID) {
        this.personName = personName;
        this.personID = personID;
    }

    //getters and setters

    public String getPersonName() {
        return personName;
    }

    public void setPersonName(String personName) {
        this.personName = personName;
    }

    public String getPersonID() {
        return personID;
    }

    public void setPersonID(String personID) {
        this.personID = personID;
    }
}
```

Can somebody explain why both of these constructors have been written rather than just one or the other?

Comment: We can't know *why* they've written both. Maybe they want to be able to create a person without a name or ID and only set it after construction?

Comment: because `personName` and `personID` are not mandatory for the class that extends `Person` at construction time? but you need to ask the dev who wrote that

Comment: Also: technically this is not a default constructor. The default constructor is only the auto-generated one when you have no other constructor. What you see here is a regular no-arguments constructor.

Comment: Turning the question around... Why do you think they *shouldn't* have these constructors?  Do you have a compelling reason to change the design?  Are you free to change it?  If not, can you propose that change to whomever is in a position to change it?  It's not really up to us.

Comment: @JoachimSauer So how this would play out at the creation of an object is the person information (name and ID) would be set to NULL initially and then at the end of the object being created only then would the person's name and ID be added to the object. Am I understanding that right?

Comment: @David I can't think of any reason as to why somebody shouldn't use both constructors, but I can't see what it does to do so. If I'm understanding it correctly the code will define the object's info as default (the strings will just equal NULL), but then the strings will immediately be written as the person's name and ID. I'm more of asking if there is something that is accomplished by including both rather than just writing the abstract class without including the no-arguments constructor.

Comment: @October171 Yes that is correct. If you used the constructor with no arguments the name and id would initially be null and you would then have to call the setter methods to set those values.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Thanks.

Comment: One reason why a no-args constructor and using setters might be preferable is simply if the class would later grow. With just the 2 fields name and id setting those values in a constructor is easy and readable for coders. But imagine if the class keeps growing and ends up with 10+ String fields. If you would have to pass all of them to the constructor I'm sure after spending to much time asking yourself "did i have to pass the name as the second or seventh argument again?" you would see the advantage of using a no-args constructor and calling setters simply from a clean-code perspective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate requires a no-argument constructor, it uses reflection to call the no-arg constructor when it needs to instantiate a persistent class. So a constructor can be present due to its being needed by a library or framework.

Apparently the other constructor is there as a convenience so the programmer can set the name and ID without calling separate setters.

If you want you can make the no-arg constructor private and Hibernate  can still use it.

There is a pattern called constructor chaining (described here: [Is it good or bad to delegate to another constructor (using this()) within a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24613664/217324)) which shows how multiple constructors can make sense, but the code shown isn’t doing that.